# Spring JPA and Hibernate do not save entity to database when calling save method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem creating a Spring project using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate. When I called save method on the repository, it didn't insert my object to the database.

**Hibernate config class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.app.config" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.app.repository" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new   LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.app.model", "com.app.repository" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
      return sessionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.app.model", "com.app.repository" });
      factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      factory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
      factory.afterPropertiesSet();
      return factory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
      dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
      dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
      dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
      return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
      return hibernateTemplate;
  }

  private Properties hibernateProperties() {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
      properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
      properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
      properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
      return properties;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
      return txManager;
  }

  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
      return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  }
}
```

**Repository class:**

```
@Repository
public interface CityRepository extends BaseRepository<City, Integer> {
  City findByName(String name);
  List<City> findAll();

  @Query("SELECT c.name FROM City c")
  List<String> findAllCityName();
}
```

**Service class:**

```
@Service
public class CityService {

   @Autowired
   private CityRepository cityRepository;

   public void saveCity(City city) {
      return cityRepository.save(city);
  }
}
```

`BaseRepository` is extended by `CrudRepository` in Spring JPA.
The code above runs without any errors but entity was not saved to the DB. Does anyone know what the issue with my code is?

Comment: Where so you call `save`? Where do you make a commit?

Comment: Drop the sessionFactory, drop the hibernateTemplate, replace the HibernateTransactionManager by a JpaTransactionManager.

Comment: The service doesnt seem to be transactional.. try to add @Transactional annotation on the class or method

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, your answer helps me alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved my problem by follow answer from JB Nizet above.

> Drop the sessionFactory, drop the hibernateTemplate, replace the HibernateTransactionManager by a JpaTransactionManager. – JB Nizet